# Probability of choosing a point $(X,Y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, density-function

Picking a point $(X,Y)$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

We first randomly generate a radius $R$ by a continuous distribution and density function $f_R$. Then, choose a point $(X,Y)$ uniformly at random inside the disc centred at $(0,0)$ with radius $R$.

Find a density function $f_R$, so that $(X,Y)$ has standard gaussian distribution of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I am not sure where to start? My only thoughts are to consider the form $(X,Y)$ should be in, in order for it to have a standard gaussian distribution and work backwards?

Comment: Interesting question. I always thought that the probability of picking a precise point at random was $0$ as the measure of the set $\{(X,Y)\}$ is always $0$.

Comment: I think you should simply pursue your idea of working backwards. What would be the form of $f_R$ is $(X,Y)$ was standard Gaussian?

Comment: You may try to consider to transform the standard bivariate gaussian pdf from rectangular coordinate to polar coordinate

Answer (score 2):

Conditionally on $R$, the density of $(X,Y)$ is
$$
f_{X,Y\mid R}(x,y\mid r)=\frac{1}{\pi r^2}1\!\left\{x^2+y^2\le r^2\right\}.
$$
Thus, the unconditional density is
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi r^2}f_R(r)\, dr.
$$
It is clear that in order to get the standard Gaussian density, $f_R(r)$ should be proportional to $r^3\cdot \exp(-r^2/2)$. You may [check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution) that $R\sim \chi_4$ in this case.